# Need help on trigger which is used to update parent record when child record value changes

Tags: trigger, field-update, master-detail, child-to-parent

Hi i have written trigger in which SC_Problem_Management__c is parent object and SC_Problem_Case_Link__c is child object having master detail relationship.
I want to update status field of parent object to awaiting deployment when all child records status having value as 'Tested'.

```
trigger updatestatus on SC_Problem_Case_Link__c(after update) {
    List<SC_Problem_Management__c> parentObjList = new List<SC_Problem_Management__c>();
    List<SC_Problem_Management__c> parentObjListToBeUpdated = new List<SC_Problem_Management__c>();
    public List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();
    for (SC_Problem_Case_Link__c childObj : Trigger.new) {
        listIds.add(childObj.SC_Problem_Management__c);
    }
    parentObjList = [SELECT Id,Status__c, (SELECT ID, Status__c FROM SC_Problem_Case_Link__r) FROM SC_Problem_Management__c WHERE ID IN :listIds];
    Boolean checkApproval = TRUE;
    for (SC_Problem_Management__c bid : parentObjList) {
        for (SC_Problem_Case_Link__c bsaa : bid.SC_Problem_Case_Link__r) {
            if (bsaa.Status__c == 'Tested') {
                checkApproval = TRUE;
            } else {
                checkApproval = FALSE;
            }
        }
        if (checkApproval == TRUE) {
            bid.Status__c = 'Awaiting Deployment';
        }
        parentObjListToBeUpdated.add(bid);
    }
    if (parentObjListToBeUpdated.size() > 0) {
        update parentObjListToBeUpdated;
    }
}
```

I am getting error while saving the trigger.
**"Error    Error: Compile Error:
Status__c,(SELECT ID, Status__c FROM SC_Problem_Case_Link__r) FROM SC_Problem_Management__c
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:48
Didn't understand relationship 'SC_Problem_Case_Link__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 9 column 21"**

Please guide on this issue.

Comment: Open the Master Detail Field,  and then check Child Relationship Name. Your inner query table would be `Child_Relationship_Name__r`

Comment: Your logic also contains an issue. If your last child record is "Tested", then your parent record will be marked as "Awaiting Deployment", even if there are other child records that aren't "Tested".

Comment: Any reason you cannot use Rollup Summary fields since you have a Master-Detail relationship? You can create a rollup summary field for count of all child records and another field to see the count of child records with status as Tested. When both counts match, a trigger / WF Rule on the parent can update the status on the parent record.

Comment: @pranay child relationship name is correct but don't know why it is showing me an error

Comment: @AayushK i have done the same thing suggested by you.but it is still not working. Could you please let me know if i am missing something.

trigger TestedStatus on SC_Problem_Management__c (After Update) 
{
  for(SC_Problem_Management__c c : Trigger.new)
        {   
            if(c.Related_Incident_Count__c == c.All_child_with_tested_status__c)
            {
                c.Status__c ='Awaiting Deployment';
            }
        }
}

Comment: This is because you are doing it in an After Update trigger. This should be done on a Before Update trigger.

Comment: Thanks Ayush. It is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the comment to the answer section so that the question can be closed.

You can use Rollup Summary fields since you have a Master-Detail relationship.

You can create a rollup summary field for count of all child records and another field to see the count of child records with status as Tested. When both counts match, a trigger (before update) / WF Rule on the parent can update the status on the parent record.